# luks IO error while decrypting keyslot

Tags: partition, 3ware, luks

I'm trying to use cryptsetup to encrypt some partitions, but getting the error `IO error while decrypting keyslot.`

The command and output is:

```
root@rescue ~ # cryptsetup --debug --verbose --cipher aes-xts-plain64 --key-size 256 --hash sha256 --iter-time 6000 luksFormat  /dev/sda3
# cryptsetup 1.6.6 processing "cryptsetup --debug --verbose --cipher aes-xts-plain64 --key-size 256 --hash sha256 --iter-time 6000 luksFormat /dev/sda3"
# Running command luksFormat.
# Locking memory.
# Installing SIGINT/SIGTERM handler.
# Unblocking interruption on signal.

WARNING!
========
This will overwrite data on /dev/sda3 irrevocably.

Are you sure? (Type uppercase yes): YES
# Allocating crypt device /dev/sda3 context.
# Trying to open and read device /dev/sda3.
# Initialising device-mapper backend library.
# Timeout set to 0 miliseconds.
# Iteration time set to 6000 miliseconds.
# Interactive passphrase entry requested.
Enter passphrase: 
Verify passphrase: 
# Formatting device /dev/sda3 as type LUKS1.
# Crypto backend (gcrypt 1.6.3) initialized.
# Detected kernel Linux 4.9.85 x86_64.
# Topology: IO (512/0), offset = 0; Required alignment is 1048576 bytes.
# Checking if cipher aes-xts-plain64 is usable.
# Using userspace crypto wrapper to access keyslot area.
IO error while decrypting keyslot.
# Releasing crypt device /dev/sda3 context.
# Releasing device-mapper backend.
# Unlocking memory.
Command failed with code 5: IO error while decrypting keyslot.
```

I did find the code which throws this error, [here](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/blob/master/lib/luks1/keyencryption.c#L199), but it doesn't offer me any insight.

As you can see from the output, the partition gets formatted, but the keyslot is not written.

/dev/sda is a 3ware raid array, the partition table was written to the device by the debian installer. I found out (by mistake), that I can create a LUKS container on the entire device, but that's not a viable workaround for me because it's the only storage device on the server and I need an unencrypted /boot partition.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out, before the command in my question, I had tried the same thing while specifying a partition by uuid, something like:

```
cryptsetup <options> luksFormat /dev/disk/by-uuid/<disk uuid>
```

during this operation the uuid will change. I don't understand the minutia, but I ended up with a corrupt partition table.